# RubyMotion and InfoPlist.strings localization

Tags: ios, rubymotion, info.plist

I want to localize some keys in `InfoPlist.strings` in RubyMotion project. I've created the language specific directories (`en.lproj` and so on), put the localized `InfoPlist.strings` files there. But it seems that the app doesn't load those files. So it uses the values from the `InfoPlist.strings` in top-level resources directory.

Actually, I don't know if rubymotion is supposed to handle those files at all, maybe it's an xcode-only thing. So I wonder if I'm doing something wrong, or is it just unsupported? If it's not supported then how can I localized the info.plist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your localized plist constants in `resources/XX.lproj/InfoPlist.strings`

In the Rakefile you can have some values like `app.info_plist['FacebookDisplayName'] = 'xx'`. I'm not sure but it may override your localized plists. Try to put your localized vars in these files only.

My localized plist:
`resources/fr.lproj/InfoPlist.strings`

`CFBundleDisplayName = "WeMoms";
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription = "Votre position nous permet d'afficher le contenu le plus adapté possible";`

Comment: Thanks, that actually works. But only if there are no `InfoPlist.strings` in the root directory, if that file exists then it seems to be always used instead of the one in the `xx.lproj` directory.